# Is it considered copyright if I use a small portion of a song to play as an alarm in my iOS app? Will my app be taken down for copyright infringement?

Tags: ios, swift, alarm

I just want to know if the following scenario is considered to be copyright infringement...

In my app, the user can accumulate points to "buy" different alarm sounds..these alarms are actual 5-10 second snippets of songs from artists...Is it considered to be copyright if I use those snippets in my app?

P.S. The app will be free download BTW

Comment: if you have to ask then it's best to avoid it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a licensing question, which is outside of the scope of the site.

Comment: The question of copyright infringement is a legal question and would depend on what legal jurisdiction the application came under.  If you are referring to the United States, you would have to look at whether or not you could argue Fair Use (https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/fair-use-the-four-factors.html).

Comment: There's no way you'll get that in the store. _From App Review guidelines_ **5.2.1** Generally: Don’t use protected third party material such as trademarks, copyrighted works, or patented ideas in your app without permission, and don’t include misleading, false, or copycat representations, names, or metadata in your app bundle or developer name. Apps should be submitted by the person or legal entity that owns or has licensed the intellectual property and other relevant rights and is responsible for offering any services provided by the app.

Answer (score 4):

Almost definitely, you are using content that you do not own to directly add value in your app without permission.